# Add Custom Bulk operations to an existing Views

Tags: 7, hooks, views

I am creating a custom bulk operation using `hook_action_info` and I can see that the operation is created successfully. But however, I want to add this to an existing views. I can do this using Views UI with editing the view and editing "Selected bulk operations". So there I can select the custom operation that I have written.

So far doing this works for me but I want to automate this one. So once I enable my module with this custom operation I need to add this custom bulk operation to the existing view's "Selected bulk operations".

Is there any hooks or alters that do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hook_views_default_views_alter() is the sauce you're after

Comment: Drupal is a CMF/CMS, not a food product

Comment: May you expand your answer? In which way should the OP use this hook?

Comment: larowlan, this solved my problem :-)